# SQL - Display fixed message based on query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL so please go easy on me if this has been asked before (I couldnt find my answer)

**Question:**
I have written a query

```
SELECT Name, 
       DATEDIFF (DAY, GETDATE(), Date_D) AS DR
FROM Project
WHERE Date_D < GETDATE()
```

What I want to achieve is the result of the query should list the Name and then say "completed" alongside it

**Outcome**

```
Name    DR
A    Completed
B    Completed
```

please can someone kindly explain how this is done.

Many thanks

Comment: What is your purpose when you write your query? Do you want to get all `Name` of project that have `Date_D` < current date, and the column `completed` alongside it?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach yes correct. So where ever the date_D is < todaysDate i want the word 'completed to be shown' near the project name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems based datediff you want to put a comment , you can use case when if that is your requirement

```
SELECT Name, 
       case when ( DATEDIFF (DAY, GETDATE(), Date_D))<0 then 'completed' else null end AS DR
FROM Project
WHERE Date_D < GETDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I just had to change the query from >0 to <0  to get my desired outcome

Answer (score 1):

You could just use this is enough:

```
SELECT Name, 
       'Completed' AS DR
FROM Project
WHERE Date_D < GETDATE();
```